# How to get specific collection name of Firebase firestore in fluttter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a application in which I manage two types of your. I store both user data in different collection, so want to navigate screen based on user type. That's why I want to collection name from Firebase Firestore, so that based on the user type I show different  screen.

[main. dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA9lS.png)
above is code of my main .dart file in which i use stream builder to identify user base on there data
[if condition where i identify snap shot has data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8bN3.png)

this is condition  where I identify  snapshot .has Data or Not if snapshot have data then it move to Tabs Screen() but I want to the identify the data base on user type & then show them different screen base on there user type . Please Help!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is the cause of your problem here. Store the users of both types in a single collection with a field in each document to indicate the user type. You can then read the user document from a known place, and navigate to the correct screen based on their type.